# Javascript replace in string

Tags: javascript, string

I would like to replace in ex:`EMPRESA@RHID->RHID_AVALIADOR@DT_ADMISSAO'`

->RHID_AVALIADOR .
Lets say that i need to replace substring that starts with '->' till next @ .

I need also the oposite way. Replace from '->' to previous @ , if '->' exists 
Apreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Be clearer : give us an exemple of input and expected output

Comment: EMPRESA@RHID->RHID_AVALIADOR@DT_ADMISSAO and then EMPRESA@RHID@DT_ADMISSAO

Comment: EMPRESA@RHID->RHID_AVALIADOR@DT_ADMISSAO and then EMPRESA@RHID_AVALIADOR@DT_ADMISSAO

Comment: `str.replace(/->[\s\S]*@/g,"whatever")` and then `str.replace(/@[\s\S]*->/g,"whatever")`

Answer (score 0):

A solution with no REGEX :

```
var input = "EMPRESA@RHID->RHID_AVALIADOR@DT_ADMISSAO";
var start = input.indexOf("@");
var stop = input.indexOf("->")
var result = input.slice(0,start+1).concat(input.slice(stop+2));
console.log(result); //EMPRESA@RHID_AVALIADOR@DT_ADMISSAO
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = 'EMPRESA@RHID->RHID_AVALIADOR@DT_ADMISSAO';

var res = str.replace(/->[A-Z_]*@/g, 'replacevalue');

alert(res);
```

This should do the trick. Uses javascript replace with regex. You may need to expand the character class, depending on the consistency of your incoming text. Replace the second value of replace() with the text you are replacing with